# Json do not work in json viewer and I dont find my issue

Tags: json

{
{
"code": "synthetic",
"name": {
"en": "Surface","fr": "Surface"
}
},
{
"code": "synthetic",
"name": {
"en": "Surface","fr": "Surface"
}
}
}

Comment: what error do you get? when i use `JSONLint.com` it tells me that you are missing something between the 1st 2 `{` items. it seems to expect _something_ there, but i don't know enuf to tell what it otta be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to represent an array of something so you need to wrap it in brackets `[]` instead of curly braces `{}`:

```
[
    { "code": "synthetic", "name": { "en": "Surface", "fr": "Surface" } },
    { "code": "synthetic", "name": { "en": "Surface", "fr": "Surface" } }
]
```

Comment: thank you its worked sorry i'm a beginner for json :)

Comment: @SimonSauro Do you mind marking my answer as correct?